# Sort Function C# Mongodb Not Working Properly

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have lets say 15 documents in a collection on mongodb atlas with a vote count value (one post may have 25 likes as example). I've already tried sorting the documents on mongo but apparently you cannot sort them within the database. My c# code is sorting them correctly, but I need to have only a specific amount of posts per page to cut down load time. What's happening is that when you switch pages, every page has 10 posts on it, in order, but they're duplicates from the last page. It looks like the sorting is happening, its skipping, and then limiting to 10. But the next page it does it all over again. Any clues how I can fix this?
Heres my code. Runcontrol and Pagecontrol are just the numbers that it needs to skip. (Page 1 = 0, and runcontrol is the count for each post. So it skips 11 documents because its already posted those).

I have some components commented out, those are my past and current solutions as I'm testing different options.

```
RunControl = 0;
        var Docs = await collection.Aggregate()
            .Sort("{Votes:-1}")
            .Skip(PageControl+RunControl)
            .Limit(10)
            .ToListAsync();
        //SortByDescending(bson => bson["Votes"])
        //var testDocs = await collection.Aggregate()
        //var cursor = await collection.Find(_ => true).Sort("{Votes:-1}").Skip(PageControl+RunControl).Limit(10).ToListAsync();
        foreach (var document in Docs.AsEnumerable())
            {
                  RunControl = RunControl + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this

```
.Skip(PageControl+RunControl)
```

instead be

```
.Skip(PageControl * RunControl)
```

for the first (0) page, you skip `0 * 10 == 0`

for the 2nd (1) page, you skip `1 * 10 == 10`

and so on

Comment: It used to work, I must have changed something. Your math is correct technically, since I'm loading ten documents at a time. However, it did use to work with addition, since I was assuming I was loading document by document but now that I read your response, I believe I'm loading 10, and then iterating through the 10 one at a time. But multiplying still doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: your code cuts off in the middle of the loop so I can't really tell what you're doing.  Have you verified what values it using for the query on each page?

Comment: Yeah so I didn't include more because It's probably 100 lines of code that utilizes the data pulled from mongo. Names, post data, vote count, date posted, etc. And it pulls all that fine for each post no issues, just doesn't populate the pages correctly.

Comment: how are you binding the data?

Comment: I found my issue was a stupid reinstatement of PageControl = 0; at the start of the function that I must have put in there at some point and don't remember why. I implemented the multiplication part you said but that didn't work, I returned it to original state and it worked. I really appreciate your help. While I have you here, if you know anything about the aggregate or find function, which one do you think is faster?